# In Django, how to update other fields (in another table) in serializers.py?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am beginner to django framework and am trying to update a `foriegn key` reference of my content, basically, there is a `Users` model as below

**models.py**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    usr_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Member(models.Model):
    mem_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    usr_id = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    mem_details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

With the above in the models in place, I am trying to create a `serializer`
with the aim that, whenever I create a instance of User table(instance), I should also update `Member table` details. Also,
in the `serializer` I am trying to do as below for the Member, but not working.

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('usr_id','name'....) #have removed other fields


class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usr_id = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
             model = Member
             fields = ('mem_id','usr_id','name'...)#removed other fields
```

this is not taking UserSerializer's usr_id and it not pushing,

Should I need to define override create method here??? Please help...

**Error am getting currently:**

```
"error": {
        "usr_id": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    },
```

Comment: If you are getting any errors, please share it

Comment: am getting as 'This field is required' message

Answer (score 0):

Found answer myself, though the answer is very easy...

i.e.. Output of one response say from Users Serializers, should be made as input of the other in the **views.py** file

```
serializer.save()
serializer_mem = MemberSerializer(data=serializer.data)
if serializer_mem.is_valid():
   .....
```